# Docker: Create Teardown Procedures

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a mechanism or section to create tear down procedures for a dockerfile instance launched as follows:

```
docker-compose up
```

And torn down:

```
docker-compose down
```

In other words, is there a location or file I can add with routines and commands for the docker virtual machine to run on teardown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most usually, container entrypoints end with a `exec $@` instruction that will replace the script process with the container command (usually the `CMD` directive if not overriden). In this cases, it is up to *that* command to feature a teardown procedure. E.g. a python program should look into [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) and [`signal.signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal). This is convenient because the command will be the actual process to receive signals (`TERM`, `INT`, `KILL`, `QUIT` and whatnot).

If the command is itself a shell script or the resources it should teardown were setup in the entrypoint script, then the script should handle the teardown! But there are some caveats to achieve this and still forward signals and exit codes:

1. The command should be directly run but not `exec`-ed. Otherwise the entrypoint wouldn't proceed execution after the command exits.
2. The teardown procedure must be set as a shell `trap`. If it was simply scripted after the command instead, there are a number of scenarios where the teardown wouldn't run (any time the command did not end on its own but was terminated externally, e.g. with `docker compose down`)
3. The trap could capture multiple signals/events so the teardwon procedure should either be idempotent or remove the trap.
4. "Setting a trap for `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP` produces undefined results."

```bash
# entrypoint.sh

setup() {
  RC=-1
  trap 'teardown' EXIT
  echo hello
}
teardown() {
  echo goodbye, exitcode=$RC
  trap - EXIT
  exit $RC
}

setup
$@  # do NOT "exec $@"
RC=$?  # try to return command's exit code if it had a natural end
```

```
# Dockerfile
# ...
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Build your image with this and play with it

```bash
docker run --rm -ti myimage false
docker run --rm -ti myimage true
docker run --rm -ti myimage bash -c 'exit 42'
docker run --rm -ti myimage sleep infinity &
kill %1
docker compose up -d
docker compose down
docker compose logs
```

Comment: good guide on how to do this w/ bash shim

Answer (score 0):

No.  Docker Compose is basically just a wrapper around `docker run`, and the lifetime of a Compose service is exactly the lifetime of its container (and its container’s entrypoint), no more and no less.

There’s a standard pattern to use an image’s `ENTRYPOINT` to do initial setup (wait for a database to be ready, run migrations, ...) and then have it launch the image’s `CMD`.  In principle you can use this same pattern to do cleanup after the `CMD` exits.  There’s nothing technically wrong with that (aside from some signal-handling concerns), it’s just not that common: usually cleaning up the container filesystem is all that needs to be done.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am docker-entrypoint.sh
# I am run with the CMD as arguments

# ... do first-time setup ...

# Run the main container process
# Usually:
#   exec "$@"
# But if you need to do things afterwards:
"$@"
RC="$?"

# ... do cleanup ...

exit "$RC"
```